# Why PIL.Image module not working in ubuntu causing error?

Tags: python, linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux

```
import PIL.Image
image = PIL.Image.open("E:\prasant photos\ppp.jpg")
```

When I run the above code, the error below occurs in Ubuntu terminal based on Windows OS:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2809, in open
fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'E:\prasant photos\ppp.jpg'
```

I have tried a lot but not found any solution.

Comment: The address is in windows format. If you are on Ubuntu, you should write address of the image in Ubuntu system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) is still Linux on the inside. There is no "Ubuntu terminal" in Windows, you launch a terminal inside of the Linux subsystem that happens to be the image of an Ubuntu installation.

---

As such, use UNIX paths, not Windows paths, to refer to files on the filesystem from within WSL. To access letter drives, the mountpoint should be `/mnt/lowercase_drive_letter`, so to access your file on the `E:` from WSL, you would use the following path:

> **Note**: The mountpoint may change depending on the image being used with WSL at the time. But generally this is where the mountpoint is by default with official images.

```sh
"/mnt/e/prasant photos/ppp.jpg"
```

If you are used to `mintty`, `cygwin`, etc. this is going to be a bit different than those, since WSL runs inside of it's own environment to provide a Linux subsystem, whereas `mintty` and `cygwin` are both simply *nix applications compiled to run natively on Windows.

Comment: Thanks@Bender The Greatest!!!! It worked successfully